# Highlighting lines *less* than 80 characters in emacs

Tags: emacs

I have a reverse problem of the usual issue of highlighting lines greater than 80 characters. I need to highlight lines that are LESS than 80 characters. I have googled but could not find any solution. I am ok with running a command and getting a dump of hte line numbers with less than 80 characters also. Inputs appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Although not an answer to your question, you may wish to consider something like a fill-column-indicator, which is a vertical line the length of the window:  https://github.com/alpaker/Fill-Column-Indicator

Comment: You may also wish to consider a simple addition to your mode-line-format -- e.g., `(:eval (propertize "%c" 'face (if (>= (current-column) 80) 'font-lock-keyword-face 'font-lock-warning-face)))`

Comment: [This page](http://www.emacswiki.org/EightyColumnRule) is the best starting point I know of for such things. Pretty much anything touted as a way to signal or highlight more than 80 columns can be made to signal or highlight less than 80 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `highlight-regexp` for this

<kbd>`M-x`</kbd> <kbd>`highlight-regexp`</kbd><kbd>`enter`</kbd><kbd>`^.\\{1,80\\}$`</kbd><kbd>`enter`</kbd><kbd>`enter`</kbd>

then use `unhighlight-regexp` to undo it. The one you entered will be in the history.

You could wrap this up in your own minor mode like this:

```lisp
(define-minor-mode highlight-less-than-80-mode
  "Minor mode for highlighting lines less than 80 characters."
  :init-value nil
  :global nil
  :lighter "<80"
  (if highlight-less-than-80-mode
      (highlight-regexp "^.\\{1,80\\}$" 'error)
    (unhighlight-regexp "^.\\{1,80\\}$")))
```

Also

I wrote [column-enforce-mode](https://github.com/jordonbiondo/column-enforce-mode/) to highlight lines longer than 80 columns, and I was able make it work the opposite way by only changing one `unless` to `if` and one `(point)` to `(point-at-bol)`. If you'd like you could also install `column-enforce-mode` from melpa and make the modifications yourself. As of 8/25/2014 the two changes need to be made on lines 200 and 202. The difference with column-enforce-mode and using highlight regexp is that it measures columns, not characters, so that may or may not be what your are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This function will dump (as a list) the line numbers of lines shorter than 80 characters:

```lisp
(defun id-short-lines (&optional nchars)
  "Returns a list of lines less than NCHARS characters
long (default: 80)."
  (let (lines)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (not (eobp))
        (when (< (- (point-at-eol) (point-at-bol)) 
                 (or nchars 80))
          (push (line-number-at-pos) lines))
        (forward-line 1))
      (nreverse lines))))
```

If this is a one-off problem (or at least a rare one), then the line dump is probably fine; otherwise, you might want to investigate the `fill-column-indicator` and faces as the comments suggest.

Comment: Thanks. Responses from both you and Jordon (highlight-regexp) worked for me. Jordon proved to be a bit more convenient since it is colored. I could choose only one as the correct answer though. Thanks again